# What is the significance of the titles of the episodes?

Tags: warrior-nun

The title of each episode of the series *Warrior Nun* comes from a book of the Bible. Some of the titles can plausibly be connected to the events of the episode, such as the title of the first episode, Psalm 46:5:

> God is within her, she will not fall;
>
> God will help her at break of day.

If one squints a bit, this could describe God not letting Ava die, and her receiving the Halo.

However, some are more obscure. For instance, the fourth episode is titled Sirach 26:9-10:

> By her eyelids and her haughty stare an unchaste wife can be
> recognized.
>
> Keep a strict watch over an unruly wife, lest, finding an
> opportunity, she make use of it;

There are not any wives in this episode, chaste or otherwise (except perhaps Dr. Salvius?). Nor is it immediately clear who might have a haughty stare, or be unruly.

So what is the significance of the episode titles?

Comment: Nuns are sometimes referred to as brides of Christ. So the title character could be the Wife in the quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decider [interviewed the showrunners](https://decider.com/2020/07/07/warrior-nun-the-hidden-meaning-behind-the-season-1-episode-titles/) and apparently have the inside scoop on what the titles refer to.

> *Warrior Nun showrummer Simon Barry told Decider that "somebody had this brilliant idea of attaching the verse headers and then letting the audience participate in figuring out what the titles were by looking up the verses."*
>
> *“For 10 episodes, we must have scrounged for maybe double or triple that maybe, that we ended up settling on 10. Really, it was trying to find the spirit of the episode and the spirit of the show, and then finding verses that captured maybe something that was ironic, or something that was specific,” Barry said. “They all have a connection to the episode they’re attached to, but they also all speak to the philosophy of the show a little bit, as well. Sometimes, it’s done in jests or irony. Sometimes it’s done in very literal terms. It was our way of including the audience in a bit of an Easter egg hunt.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Warrior Nun’ on Netflix: The Hidden Meaning Behind the Season 1 Episode Titles](https://decider.com/2020/07/07/warrior-nun-the-hidden-meaning-behind-the-season-1-episode-titles/)</sup></sub>

You can read the full article for all of the titles and their hidden meanings, but the two you've referred to are Episode 1...

> Episode 1: "Psalms 46:5"
>
> **“God is in the midst of the city; it shall not be moved; God will help it when the morning dawns.”**
>
> Warrior Nun opens with…well…an unholy battle in the middle of a coastal Spanish city. While the last Warrior Nun Sister Shannon (Melina Matthews) falls in battle, a new one lies in wait: Sister Lilith (Lorena Andrea). However when demons trace Sister Shannon’s halo to a church morgue, a desperate nun hides the holy object in an orphan’s corpse. This is how Ava becomes the Warrior Nun.
>
> Over the course of the episode, a resurrected Ava explores the city like never before and has a profound moment watching the dawn on the beach.

...and Episode 4.

> Episode 4: "Ecclesiasticus 26:11"
>
> **“Be on guard against her impudent eye, and do not be surprised if she sins against you.”**
>
> In Warrior Nun Episode 4, we finally get a glimpse at Ava’s backstory. While the nuns at the orphanage might have thought Ava was the one full of impudence, their actions — murdering disabled children rather than letting them live outside the orphanage as adults — are the sinful ones. However, this Biblical verse might also hint at what’s developing with Sister Lilith. Cardinal Duretti (Joaquim De Almeida) is teaming up with the disaffected sister to work against Father Vincent to take back the halo from Ava, whom they see as an upstart pretender.